# Neural network back propagation fails to overfit small data

Tags: neural-network, racket, backpropagation

I'm trying to implement neural network with back propagation algorithm in Racket. To test the implementation, I decided to train it on a very small data for large amount of iterations, and see if it fits the data it was trained on. However it does not -- using the sigmoid function it outputs extremely small values (of the magnitude of -20), but relative values is correct (that is, the input vector with biggest target value also produces the biggest value in the trained network). Using relu function, the outputs by their magnitued are closer to desired, but incorrect relative to each other. I'd be glad to receive any insight, on why it is so.

```
#lang racket

; activation function. Fn - function, dfn - its derirative
(define-struct activation (fn dfn))

;activation using sigmoid
(define sigmoid-a (let ([sigmoid (lambda (x)
                                   (/ 1 (+ 1 (exp (* x -1)))))])
                    (activation (lambda(x)
                                  (sigmoid x))
                                (lambda(x)
                                  (*(sigmoid x) (- 1 (sigmoid x)))))))

; activation using relu
(define relu-a (activation (lambda(x) (if (< x 0)
                                          (* 0.2 x)
                                          x))
                           (lambda(x) (if (< x 0)
                                          0.2
                                          1))))
; neuron. Bias is implicit first weight
(define-struct neuron (weights) #:transparent )

; neuron output before applying activation function
(define (neuron-out-unactivated neuron inputs)
  (foldl (lambda(w in result)
           (+ result (* w in)))
         0
         (neuron-weights neuron)
         (cons -1 inputs)))

; neuron output with activation function applied
(define (neuron-out neuron inputs activation-fn)
  (activation-fn (neuron-out-unactivated neuron inputs)))

; neuron layer
(define-struct layer (neurons) #:transparent )

; list of layer's neurons' output, before activation function
(define (layer-out-unactivated layer inputs)
  (map (lambda(neuron)
         (neuron-out-unactivated neuron inputs))
       (layer-neurons layer)))

; list of layer's neurons' output with activation function applied
(define (layer-out layer inputs activation-fn)
  (map (lambda(neuron)
         (neuron-out neuron inputs activation-fn))
       (layer-neurons layer)))

; neural network
(define-struct neural-network (layers activation) #:transparent)

; neural network output 
(define (neural-network-out nn inputs)
  (let pass ([layers (neural-network-layers nn)]
             [inputs inputs])
    (if (empty? layers) inputs
        (pass (rest layers)
              (layer-out (first layers)
                         inputs
                         (activation-fn (neural-network-activation nn)))))))

; calculating derirative for the neuron in the last (output) layer
; out-unactivated -- neuron's output before applying activation function
; target-- teaching data / desired result
; activation -- activation fn and its derirative
(define (d-lastlayer out-unactivated target activation)
  (let ([result (* (- ((activation-fn activation) out-unactivated) target) ((activation-dfn activation) out-unactivated))])
    result))

; calculating derirative for the neuron in the inner (hidden) layer
; neuron-index -- place of the neuron in its layer. Needed, because weights are stored in the next layer's neurons.
; out-unactivated -- neuron's output before applying activation function
; d-nextlayer -- deriratives of the next layer
; activation -- activation fn and its derirative
(define (d-innerlayer neuron-index out-unactivated d-nextlayer nextlayer activation)
  (define mp (map (lambda (neur d)
                    (let* ([w (list-ref (neuron-weights neur) 
                                        (add1 neuron-index))]
                           [result (* d w)])
                      result))
                  (layer-neurons nextlayer)
                  d-nextlayer))
  (* (foldl + 0 mp) 
     ((activation-dfn activation) out-unactivated)))

; maps list of layers into list of layer deriratives, where each layer derirative is a list of its neuron deriratives 
(define (backpropagation layers inputs targets activation)
  (let ([output (layer-out-unactivated (first layers) inputs)])
    (if (empty? (rest layers)) 
        (list (map (lambda (out target) (d-lastlayer out target activation)) output targets))
        (let ([next-layer-d (backpropagation (rest layers) output targets activation)])
          (cons (map (lambda(index out)
                       (d-innerlayer index 
                                     out 
                                     (first next-layer-d)
                                     (first (rest layers))
                                     activation)) 
                     (range (length output)) 
                     output) 
                next-layer-d)))))

; calculates new weights for the layer.
(define (transform-layer _layer input derirative train-speed)
  (layer (map (lambda(n d)
                (neuron (map (lambda(w i)
                               (+ w (* (- train-speed) i d))) 
                             (neuron-weights n) 
                             (cons -1 input)))) 
              (layer-neurons _layer)
              derirative)))

; calculates new weights for all layers
(define (update-layers layers inputs deriratives train-speed activation-fn)
  (if (empty? layers) '()
      (cons (transform-layer (first layers)
                             inputs
                             (first deriratives)
                             train-speed) 
            (update-layers (rest layers)
                           (layer-out (first layers)
                                      inputs
                                      activation-fn)
                           (rest deriratives)
                           train-speed
                           activation-fn))))

; performs network update for single input vector
(define (train-neural-network-iteration network inputs target train-speed)
  (let* ([layers (neural-network-layers network)]
         [activation (neural-network-activation network)]
         [deriratives (backpropagation layers inputs target activation)]
         [new-layers (update-layers layers inputs deriratives train-speed (activation-fn activation))])
    (neural-network new-layers (neural-network-activation network))))

; performs network update for each input in teaching-data
(define (train-neural-network-epoch network teaching-data train-speed)
  (let train ([network network]
              [data teaching-data])
    (if (empty? data) network
        (train (train-neural-network-iteration network (car (first data)) (cdr (first data)) train-speed) (rest data)))))

; Trains network for `iterations` amount of epochs
(define (train-neural-network network data iterations train-speed)
  (let it ([i 0] [network network])
    (if (> i iterations) network
        (it (add1 i) (train-neural-network-epoch network data train-speed)))))

; creates a network. Neuron count list -- a list of integers, each telling how many neurons in that layer
(define (create-neural-network inputs-length neuron-count-list activation)
  (let _create ([inputs-l inputs-length] [n-count neuron-count-list] [layers '()])
    (if (empty? n-count) (neural-network (reverse layers) activation)
        (_create (first n-count)
                 (rest n-count)
                 (cons (layer (build-list (first n-count)
                                          (lambda (n)
                                            (neuron (build-list (add1 inputs-l)
                                                                (lambda(n2) (/ (+ (random 50) 14) 64)))))))
                       layers)))
    ))

;test
(define (test-case act)
(define nn (create-neural-network 1 (list 3 1) act))
(define data (list (cons (list 0) (list 0))
                   (cons (list 1) (list 1))
                   (cons (list 2) (list 0))))
(define trained-nn (train-neural-network nn data 1000000 0.001))
(println (~a (neural-network-out trained-nn (list 0))))
(println (~a (neural-network-out trained-nn (list 1))))
(println (~a (neural-network-out trained-nn (list 2))))
(println (~a trained-nn)))

(test-case sigmoid-a)
;outputs
;0->2 * 10^(-29)
;1->5 * 10^(-21)
;2->2 * 10^(-31)

(test-case relu-a)
;outputs
;0 -> ~164
;1 -> ~164
;2 -> ~0

(provide (all-defined-out))
```

Comment: I think https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the recursive call of the `backpropogation` function --

`(let ([next-layer-d (backpropagation (rest layers) output targets activation)])`

Output here is the output of current layer *before* activation function, however it should've been *after*.